# What, if anything, do _v, _c and _o refer to in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, pikaday

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask.

I am learning JavaScript OOP and am practicing by modifying and exploring the [Pikaday date picker](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/blob/master/pikaday.js)

I've noticed throughout the script there are references to _v, _c and _o, usually in connection to `self` or `this`, eg:

```
self._onMouseDown = function(e)
        {
            if (!self._v) {
                return;
            }
```

I can't seem to find where these are instantiated or made into functions. Are they shorthand for something? Some common practice I don't understand?

Comment: Have you browsed the source? `this._v = true;` at `1137`, `this._v = false;` at `1160`

Comment: They are just members of some object the date picker is using.

Comment: They're possibly inherited from another object.

Comment: They're just identifiers. There's no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments these have no special meaning in OO JavaScript, but I do know what they refer to in this specific case (Pikaday). _o is short for options, _v is short for visible. Haven't figured out what _c means yet, though I do know it is a true / false flag. The fact that they are prefixed with an underscore likely indicates they are private variables.